# How to create naming conventions for a fantasy society with its own language?

Tags: language, worldbuilding-process, names

I'm not a proper linguist or anything, but over the years I've created a fairly basic language for a magic people that I use in my D&D games. So far I've got by with them being ancient and long gone, so I've never really needed to give them any meaningful names. That said, in my recent game and the one I'm developing to run next, I wanted them to be more prominent and even still be alive possibly.

Currently, the naming convention I have is 2 or 3 words slapped together and either "i" or "ia" added to the end to specify male or female. Which I find very lazy and partly cliche.

What I want to do is create names that are separate of the language, but still clearly from it. I've tried to look up how names came about and the like, but I can't seem to find anyone asking this question. That all said, anyone know ways or have any tips how I could add a naming convention or even a list of names to my language?

Any help or direction is appreciated!

Comment: The trouble with this sort of thing is you really can do whatever you like. Anne McCaffrey quite happily ended all women's names with an 'a'  and all dragons with 'th' for the entire Pern series. So don't worry about the cliché. D&D is pretty clichéd to start with, you might as well embrace it.

Comment: Actually in most languages names are regular words. English and other modern European languages are unusual in this sense, because we use names taken from foreign languages (mostly Hebrew, e.g., Anna, Mary and John, and Greek or Latin). For example, Greek or Germanic names are usually two-word compounds; you may have heard of Alex-andros (Defender of Men), Cleo-patra (Glory of the Father), Bere-nice (Bringer of Victory), Aristo-teles (Noble Goal), Archi-medes (Chief Guardian), Phil-ippos (Lover of Horses), Adel-aide (Noble Nature), Lut-her (People's Army), Brun-hild (Victorious Armor)...

Comment: I commend your attention to [The Language Construction Kit](https://zompist.com/kit.html); Mr Rosenfelder offers ideas and techniques for creating your language, and discusses the issue of "naming languages" vs. languages that are "actually used".

Comment: Questions about naming things (whether asking for a name or asking for the process of finding a name) are always closed.  Here's the problem: You're asking for a process to facilitate a convention.  But how you do you develop a convention? with another process... which is based on another convention that requires another process....  There is no subjective beginning to this cycle.  We can only invite you to two solutions: (a) do what you want and (b) visit [conlang.se] and learn about how to create constructed languages.